# Week number formula for date and time column

Tags: column, date-time

What calculated field formula would show me the week number for a date and time like this:
5/27/2012 6:00 AM
All the formulas I found are only for dates.

Comment: Have you actually tried them? It shouldn't matter if input is date or date time. Also which region are you in - different regions have very different rules for calculating a week.

Comment: I got it figured out with some excel work...Thanks though